# Can I create a series of polygons for diferent categories (minimum convex polygon) on R (sf package)

Tags: r, geospatial, polygon, r-sf

I'm working with spatial information (*sf*) in R, and I have a list of species with their respective occurrence points.

I would like to obtain a polygon for each species using the *st_convex_hull* function. I have managed to create a polygon for all my points, but I am unable to group them by the species variable.

Here is the script with what I have so far:

```
#Library
library(sf)
library(tidiverse)
library(mapview)

#create data frame
lat <- c(15.53033,15.53033,15.5219,15.1739,19.08333,17.13333,18.09861,21.27667,25.54863,18.80907,25.54147,
        20.0605,23.299,25.5501,25.55005,25.54997)
lon <- c(-92.802,-92.802,-92.7997,-92.3361,-96.9667,-91.9333,-94.4297,-99.2117,-100.271,-99.2168,-100.272,-97.4713,
         -106.443,-100.27,-100.27,-100.27)
species <- c("Sp1", "Sp1","Sp1", "Sp1","Sp1", "Sp1","Sp1", "Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2")
df <- data.frame(lat, lon, species)

#create spatial matrix
df.1<- df %>%
sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"),crs="EPSG: 4326")
mapview::mapview(df.1) #View map
```

[image]

```
#create polygon for the points
sp1_mcp <- st_convex_hull(st_union(df.1))
```

So far, everything is going well, but I would like it to generate different polygons depending on the values of "species" of my data frame. The real issue is that my database consists of 200 species, which is why I want to automate the process.

Finally, I would also like to be able to save the shapefiles (.shp) as files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply the same logic as when aggregating non-spatial datasets with `dplyr`: `group_by` followed by `summarise()` that returns one record per group. With `sf` objects `summarise()` without any extra parameters only summarises geometry, so here it would return an union of points, a `MULTIPOINT`, that you can pass to `st_convex_hull()`

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(mapview)

# create data frame
lat <- c(15.53033,15.53033,15.5219,15.1739,19.08333,17.13333,18.09861,21.27667,25.54863,18.80907,25.54147,
        20.0605,23.299,25.5501,25.55005,25.54997)
lon <- c(-92.802,-92.802,-92.7997,-92.3361,-96.9667,-91.9333,-94.4297,-99.2117,-100.271,-99.2168,-100.272,-97.4713,
         -106.443,-100.27,-100.27,-100.27)
species <- c("Sp1", "Sp1","Sp1", "Sp1","Sp1", "Sp1","Sp1", "Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2")
df <- data.frame(lat, lon, species)

df.1 <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"),crs="EPSG:4326") %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise() %>% 
  st_convex_hull()

df.1
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -106.443 ymin: 15.1739 xmax: -91.9333 ymax: 25.5501
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   species                                                               geometry
#> * <chr>                                                            <POLYGON [°]>
#> 1 Sp1     ((-92.3361 15.1739, -92.7997 15.5219, -96.9667 19.08333, -91.9333 17.…
#> 2 Sp2     ((-99.2168 18.80907, -106.443 23.299, -100.27 25.5501, -97.4713 20.06…

# visualise
mapview(df.1)
```

[image]

```r
# save shp
dir.create("species")
st_write(df.1, "species/species.shp")
#> Writing layer `species' to data source 
#>   `species/species.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Writing 2 features with 1 fields and geometry type Polygon.

# check resulting shp
fs::dir_tree("species/")
#> species/
#> ├── species.dbf
#> ├── species.prj
#> ├── species.shp
#> └── species.shx
st_layers("species/")
#> Driver: ESRI Shapefile 
#> Available layers:
#>   layer_name geometry_type features fields crs_name
#> 1    species       Polygon        2      1   WGS 84
read_sf("species/")
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -106.443 ymin: 15.1739 xmax: -91.9333 ymax: 25.5501
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   species                                                               geometry
#>   <chr>                                                            <POLYGON [°]>
#> 1 Sp1     ((-92.3361 15.1739, -92.7997 15.5219, -96.9667 19.08333, -91.9333 17.…
#> 2 Sp2     ((-99.2168 18.80907, -106.443 23.299, -100.27 25.5501, -97.4713 20.06…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks you so much!
It war clarly explained and ressolved my question!

Comment: @ÁlvaroScuack , glad it helped. You also have an option to mark this ( or any other upcoming answer) as "accepted" to indicate that it worked for you.

Comment: `df %>% 
  sfheaders::sf_multipoint(x = "lon", y = "lat", multipoint_id = "species") %>%
  sf::st_convex_hull()` to save a vew steps if you want.